# Lock Mysql table for write but allow read

Tags: php, mysql, locking

Is there a way to lock a Mysql table only for write, so that another script can still make a SELECT query?

I'm using this code to write to a table (executes almost every second):

```
mysql_query("LOCK TABLES table WRITE;");
mysql_query("insert into...
mysql_query("UNLOCK TABLES;");
```

and this to select (this script just freezes, probably because of the lock):

```
mysql_query("select * from...
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

> WRITE lock:
>
> Only the session that holds the lock
>   can access the table. No other session
>   can access it until the lock is
>   released.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/lock-tables.html